# Validate uniqueness of a profile property in ASP.Net (MVC 3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, optimization, unique, asp.net-profiles

I'm using my own profile provider in my MVC 3 ASP.Net application. I have impremented this like in this [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/19/writing-a-custom-asp-net-profile-class.aspx) using a ProfileBase class.

My problem is that I have a property that I want unique called "BlogSpace". How can I validate this?

For the moment, I have created a static method in the UserProfile class that is called in the controller before trying to save. Like this:

```
public static bool ValidateUniquenessBlogSpace(string blogspace, string currentUsername, MembershipUserCollection col)
    {
        bool bUnique = true;

        foreach (MembershipUser user in col)
        {
            UserProfile userprofile = Create(user.UserName) as UserProfile;
            if (userprofile.BlogSpace == blogspace && userprofile.UserName != currentUsername)
                return false;
        }

        return bUnique;
    }
```

The main problem is that it go through all of the member so if my user base grow I'm not sure it will be very fast. <strike>The other problem is that by calling this from the controller, I'm not sure how to return to the view that the problem comes from this field and show an appropriate message...</strike>(see edit). I would like an approach like this but this only work with a database:

```
    public class UniqueBlogSpace : ValidationAttribute
            {
                public override bool IsValid(object value)
                {
                    DataContext db = new DataContext();
                    var userWithTheSameBlogSpace = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(
                        u => u.BlogSpace == (string)value);
                    return userWithTheSameBlogSpace == null;
                }
            }

[UniqueBlogSpace(ErrorMessage = "This name is already in use...")]
        public string BlogSpace { get; set; }
```

***EDIT***

I now know how to communicate to my model that a field is having problem like this in the controller. The main problem is still that the way to parse all the member will be very slow if my user base grow. Is there a better way to validate uniqueness?

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Blogspace", new System.Exception());
```

Comment: Hi. I have the exact same requirement. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: I currently use the first snipped of code of my question... It works but like I said, I'm affraid it will scale badly when my use base will be bigger... If you found anything better than that, please share! :)